# Oracle : Swapping table names

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to load a table with ~18M records in a daily basis, and in order to minimize the down time on the client side, we have the approach of loading a temp then swap the table names after. see process below

Table A is the orginal table, Table TMP is the temporary table

1. load Table TMP
2. rename Table A to Table A_V1
3. rename Table TMP to Table A
4. rename Table A_V1 to Table TMP
5. truncate Table TMP in preparation for next load

Is there any other way of swapping the table names? or any other way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a synonym.

Firstly load into `TABLEA_YYYYMMDD`, recreate constraints etc.

Then,

```
create or replace synonym tablea for tablea_yyyymmdd
```

Lastly, if you want to, drop the **previous** `tablea_yyyymmdd`.

Comment: As an alternate using the same concept, you could create a view in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Rather than actually renaming the tables, you could have two tables, `A1` and `A2`, and two synonyms, `A` and `TEMP`, which you then switch between the tables each day.

Honestly though, I think renaming the tables is probably just as valid a way to go, but since you asked for other ways it could be done, I thought I'd chip in.

Answer (score 0):

That's the best way to do it.  You could drop and recreate the tables instead of truncating if you liked.  Good Luck!